# Google Chrome not updating for last options in HTML select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue trying to create an HTML file that runs completely offline (except for loading in jQuery for the script).

The page allows the user to first select a state from the state select menu. This triggers an event in which all of the counties of a second select menu are looped through and the ones belonging to the selected state are shown, the others hidden.

In Google Chrome (the only browser I am concerned about at the moment) the last two states in my list (Oklahoma and Tennessee) correctly trigger the event and subsequently their inline style is changed to block from  none by jQuery. However, in Chrome I am unable to click on the county list and see the counties displayed. If I change the order in which the counties are ordered in the list, it is always the last two states that do not display their corresponding counties. If I comment out any two state's counties, then all state's counties that are  not commented are displayed.

All code is in a JSFiddle (less table bodies): https://jsfiddle.net/kb7mnyr1/

Code to show counties (which is required for JSFiddle link):

```
function changeCounty(state){
        $countylist = $('#countySelect').find('option');
        $countylist.hide();
        $.each($countylist, function(i, val){
        if($(val).attr('class') == state) $(val).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: first thing i would suggest is to stop using global variables..

Comment: Could be an issue with too many elements... if you comment out a number of the `option`s, then they seem to work

Comment: Noted. No more global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try only populating the `select` with the relevant elements when you need them:

```
$countylist.empty().append(counties[state]);
```

where `counties` is an object mapping `counties[state] = [$county1option, $county2option, ...]`

It seems to work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kb7mnyr1/3/)

Note that the way that the object is generated right now is very bad (simply takes the values that were in the select, populates the object, and removes them from the select).

You should generate this directly in JS instead of having to jump through those steps and doing so is an exercise left for the reader (make a JS object `{state: [counties], state2: [counties], ...}` and dynamically generate the options as needed with jQuery instead of prepopulating in your HTML).

Comment: Still curious about why it didn't work previously but this is a much better method (once the counties are loaded directly) that I hadn't considered. Thanks for the insight!